# DIV borders not lining up

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a table with 3 divs using flex box, but when I add a border to the div's the border isn't lining up on top of the next div. Anyone with an eagle eye spot what I'm missing?
Thanks!

```css
.content div {
  width: 350px;
  border: solid;
  padding: 6px;
}

p {
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.red {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.green {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blue {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="red"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7YJB7QC/flag.png" alt="flag" border="0" width="40" height="40">
    <p>100% Made in the USA</p>
  </div>
  <div class="green"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/dmDyGKH/100.png" alt="100" border="0" width="40" height="40">
    <p>100% Happiness Guaranteed</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blue"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/zmK0Jk0/check.png" alt="check" border="0" width="40" height="40">
    <p>100% Secure Checkout</p>
  </div>
  <table>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Because flexbox does not have border-collapse? Is that what you mean?

Comment: They are lining up,  but borders go around the entire div. So you're seeing the bottom border of the top div and the top border of the next div touching. You could have the middle div's border-top and border-bottom set to none.

Comment: good use of code snippet, @jackstrum.  welcome to SO

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the thick borders its because of the box-model, the borders from each element are right underneath each other making it look like the border is 2px. A good trick is to have no top or bottom borders on each element and then adjust either the first or last one.

This was my solution, I applied a border-bottom of none to all the items and the added the border back to the bottom of the last element.

```
.content div {
  width: 350px;
  border: solid;
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.content div:last-child {
  border-bottom: solid;
}
```

```css
.content div {
  width: 350px;
  border: solid;
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.content div:last-child {
  border-bottom: solid;
}

p {
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.red {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.green {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blue {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="red"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7YJB7QC/flag.png" alt="flag" border="0" width="40" height="40">
    <p>100% Made in the USA</p>
  </div>
  <div class="green"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/dmDyGKH/100.png" alt="100" border="0" width="40" height="40">
    <p>100% Happiness Guaranteed</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blue"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/zmK0Jk0/check.png" alt="check" border="0" width="40" height="40">
    <p>100% Secure Checkout</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.content div:last-child` will not work.

Comment: You are right I didnt see that empty table at the bottom of the content div. Jack do you need that empty table there? If you remove it, it will work - see code snippet for update

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox items don't collapse borders.

If you want the borders to operate like table borders, `display` them like `table`, `table-row`, and `table-cell`:

```css
div.content {
  width: 350px;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

div.content div.row {
  border: solid 2px black;
  display: table-row;
}

div.row p {
  display: table-cell;
}

div.content div.row img {
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="red row">
    <p>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/7YJB7QC/flag.png" alt="flag"></img>

      100% Made in the USA
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="green row">

    <p>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/dmDyGKH/100.png" alt="100"></img>
      100% Happiness Guaranteed
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="blue row">
    <p>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zmK0Jk0/check.png" alt="check"></img>

      100% Secure Checkout
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The OP uses the word "table", but it isn't a table in the HTML sense - from their snippet it looks like its just their way of describing the layout (and as you know, using a HTML table for that is definitely not the way to go :) )

Comment: in that table display collapses borders, I think it's defensible.  In that it's not really columnar data, you're right, `<table>` and friends have no place.  `display: table` is better.

Answer (score -2):

Try setting a thickness for the border, such as `1px`:

```css
.content div {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

Comment: The problems persists.